# Connect4 on Android, timing issue

Tags: java, android, game-engine, minimax

I'm developing a simple Connect4 game in Android.

Currently I'm using a minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning and bit-board state representation so the search is very effective and fast.

The skill is set by setting the maximum depth the algorithm should reach during its DFS search inside the game tree.

I noticed that the time required to choose a move depends on how far we are in the game: at the beginning it takes more time (as there are many possibilities to explore), in mid-game it take a reasonable amount of time and near the end is very fast.

My problem is that if I set a given skill the user has to wait to much on the first/second/third moves. I'd like to speed-up the aperture but I suspect it depends even on the hardware itself how I want to implement the speed-up process.

Can I set a timeout for the thread running the DSF mimimax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to circumvent this issue is to use an opening book for the first few moves. An opening book is a set of predetermined moves for a given scenario. Since there are relatively few possibly board states for the opening moves, you can easily compile a database of all possibly moves for the first three turns, and call upon it instead of actually doing the search. Thus you no longer require a time out and you sped up the search with zero cost to accuracy.